# cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer un botón de añadido rápido al carrito pero tengo un problema y es que me arroja el error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Estoy usando ajax  y php. No sé cual podría ser el problema por eso acudo a ustedes, les dejo el código en cuestión:

**`codigo php:`**

```
$registros2=mysqli_query($conexion,"select id_producto, nombre, precio, descripcion, id_categoria from productos where inicio=1 LIMIT ".$inicio."," . $TAMANO_PAGINA);
$fila2=mysqli_fetch_array($registros2);
```

**`codigo html:`**

```
<form name="formAnadirCarrito">

    <input type="text" name="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($fila2['nombre']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="precio_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['precio']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad_producto" value="1" maxlength=2>
    <input type="text" name="id_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['id_producto']; ?>">
    <button type="button" onclick="anadirAlCarrito()" class="botonCarrito">Añadir al carrito</button>
</form>
```

**`codigo js:`**

```
function anadirAlCarrito(){

    var nombre_producto=document.formAnadirCarrito.nombre_producto.value;
    var precio_producto=document.formAnadirCarrito.precio_producto.value;
    var cantidad_producto=document.formAnadirCarrito.cantidad_producto.value;
    var id_producto=document.formAnadirCarrito.id_producto.value;


    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"compra/carrito.php",
            data:{"nombre_producto":nombre_producto,"precio_producto":precio_producto,
            "cantidad_producto":cantidad_producto,"id_producto":id_producto},

            // beforeSend:function(){

            //  },

            success:function(respuesta){

                    $("#contenedor_carrito").html(respuesta);
                    $("#contenedor_carrito").show("fast");
                    $("#menu").load(location.href + " #menu");
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: Hola! Revisa si los values son puestos correctamente en el html rendereado por php, probablemente sea eso.

Comment: Quita las comillas a las claves de tu variable `data`, las que están a la izquierda. También, los inputs que muestras con código PHP mezclado da la impresión de que son erróneos. Sería mejor sacar esos valores en variables para escribir un código más claro y manejar la codificación utf-8 a un nivel más global, para evitar luego aplicar funciones de codificación por todas partes.  ¿En que línea te está marcando el error?

Comment: Todas sus respuestas me funcionaron, pero a medias. Quiero decir que ahora si introduce el producto en el carrito pero siempre es el primer producto, no importa si hago click sobre el ultimo producto o el tercero, siempre agrega al carrito el primer producto.

Comment: Eso es porque no capturas el evento del botón, en otras palabras no identificas que botón fue presionado, busca como capturar el botón que disparo el click o prueba con la respuesta JQuery de @fran_ivan

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cannot read property 'call' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476803/cannot-read-property-call-of-undefined-typeerror-cannot-read-property-call)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba esto, solo cambie el tipo de búsqueda para que sea por Id cualquier cosa me comentas:

```js
function anadirAlCarrito(){

    var nombre_producto=document.getElementById('nombre_producto').value;
    var precio_producto=document.getElementById('precio_producto').value;
    var cantidad_producto=document.getElementById('cantidad_producto').value;
    var id_producto=document.getElementById('id_producto').value;

    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"compra/carrito.php",
            data:{nombre_producto:nombre_producto,precio_producto:precio_producto,
            cantidad_producto:cantidad_producto,id_producto:id_producto},

            // beforeSend:function(){

            //  },

            success:function(respuesta){

                    $("#contenedor_carrito").html(respuesta);
                    $("#contenedor_carrito").show("fast");
                    $("#menu").load(location.href + " #menu");
            }

        });
}
```

```html
<form name="formAnadirCarrito">
    <input type="text" id="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($fila2['nombre']); ?>">
    <input type="text" id="precio_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['precio']; ?>">
    <input type="text" id="cantidad_producto" value="1" maxlength=2>
    <input type="text" id="id_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['id_producto']; ?>">
    <button type="button" onclick="anadirAlCarrito()" class="botonCarrito">Añadir al carrito</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera más simple de reducir el código con [**Jquery**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Lo que te recomiendo es que sigas la documentacion oficial ya que **"success" esta depreciado en la versión 3.0**

Lo mas recomendable es que si usas el "document" utilices ID's en tus inputs para extraer el valor correctamente y quitar las comillas del data

Usando Javascript

```
<form id="anadirCarrito">

    <input type="text" name="nombre_producto" id="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($fila2['nombre']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="precio_producto" id="precio_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['precio']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad_producto" id="cantidad_producto" value="1" maxlength=2>
    <input type="text" name="id_producto" id="id_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['id_producto']; ?>">
    <button type="button" onclick="anadirAlCarrito()" class="botonCarrito">Añadir al carrito</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function anadirAlCarrito(){
    var nombre_producto = document.getElementById('nombre_producto').value;
    var precio_producto = document.getElementById('precio_producto').value;
    var cantidad_producto = document.getElementById('cantidad_producto').value;
    var id_producto = document.getElementById('id_producto').value;

    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"compra/carrito.php",
            data:{nombre_producto:nombre_producto,precio_producto:precio_producto,
            cantidad_producto:cantidad_producto,id_producto:id_producto},

            // beforeSend:function(){

            //  },

            success:function(respuesta){

                    $("#contenedor_carrito").html(respuesta);
                    $("#contenedor_carrito").show("fast");
                    $("#menu").load(location.href + " #menu");
            }

        });
    }

</script>
```

Usando **$(this).serialize()** de JQUERY

```
<form id="anadirCarrito">
    <input type="text" name="nombre_producto" value="<?php echo utf8_encode($fila2['nombre']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="precio_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['precio']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="cantidad_producto" value="1" maxlength=2>
    <input type="text" name="id_producto" value="<?php echo $fila2['id_producto']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Añadir al carrito" >
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//Escuchamos el evento submit
$("#anadirCarrito").submit(function(){
//Ingresamos tu codigo en ajax

    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"compra/carrito.php",
            //Obtenemos todas la variables que estan dentro 
            //del form es el equivalente a tu objeto ejemp: "{x:x,a:a}"
           //nota :los inputs de tu form por obligación siempre deben llevar el name
            data:$(this).serialize(),


            success:function(respuesta){
                    //#lo que responde tu carrito.php
                    console.log(respuesta);
                    //$("#contenedor_carrito").html(respuesta);
                    //$("#contenedor_carrito").show("fast");
                    //$("#menu").load(location.href + " #menu");

            }

        });

});

});
</script>
```

Y solo imprimes de lado tu archivo carrito.php los parametros

```
<?php 

var_dump($_POST); 
//Tu codigo que realiza la demás operación
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

cambia el script de JavaScript por este

```
function anadirAlCarrito(){
    var form=document.querySelector('[name="formAnadirCarrito"]');
    var nombre_producto=form.elements.nombre_producto.value;
    var precio_producto=form.elements.precio_producto.value;
    var cantidad_producto=form.elements.cantidad_producto.value;
    var id_producto=form.elements.id_producto.value;


    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"compra/carrito.php",
            data:{"nombre_producto":nombre_producto,"precio_producto":precio_producto,
            "cantidad_producto":cantidad_producto,"id_producto":id_producto},

            // beforeSend:function(){

            //  },

            success:function(respuesta){

                    $("#contenedor_carrito").html(respuesta);
                    $("#contenedor_carrito").show("fast");
                    $("#menu").load(location.href + " #menu");
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: hola tu respuesta funciona pero, siempre añade el primer producto, no importa si hago click en el botón de otro producto.

Comment: @jmz de lo que vi en tu pregunta no veo donde se pueden cambiar los productos

Comment: lo que pasa es que no añadí todo el código, pero esta respuesta no me deja añadir el código restante.