# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Soy nuevo en *JavaScript* y *JQuery*, y tengo el siguiente error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Cuando intento lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const bloques = $('#main').children()
    console.log(bloques.map())
});
```

Y el siguiente error con `.values`:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: bloques.values is not a function TypeError: bloques.values is not a function
> at HTMLDocument.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const bloques = $('#main').children()
    console.log(bloques.values())
});
```

No tengo ni idea de lo que significa. Se supone que la constante bloques es un objeto, y con *values* o *map* debería de darme los valores del objeto ¿no?.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el inspector para previsualizar, vas probando primero `$`, luego `$('#main')`, `$('#main').chil`y así... incluso te rellena automaticamente el texto que hace falta en caso de que el método exista para ese objeto, así puedes saber si un objeto jquery tiene el método `.values()` o cuales tiene que comiencen con 'v'. Además de que puedes ver que objeto te devuelve y explorar sus atributos ahí mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, la función `children()` devuelve un objeto que representa el conjunto de elementos del **DOM** que son hijos del elemento seleccionado. Pero la función `map()` (`Array.prototype.map()`), necesita actuar sobre un **array**.

La función `values()` existe para aplicarla sobre un objeto, pero la sintaxis sería (basándome en mi **HTML** de ejemplo) algo como esto:

```
Object.values(frutas)
```

Pero esta función no es lo que pretendes conseguir, porque te devolvería los valores del objeto de **JQuery** que contiene los elementos del **DOM** seleccionados. Este objeto es muy grande y la mayoría es meta-información para que **JQuery** pueda hacer su magia. El objeto está pensado para que obtengamos la información por medio de las funciones que la **API** de **JQuery** pone a nuestra disposición.

Si quieres obtener datos sobre esos hijos puedes iterarlos por medio de la función `each()`.

```js
$(function () {
  let frutas = $('.frutas').children();
  
  frutas.each(function () {
    let fruta = $(this);
    
    console.log(fruta.text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="frutas">
  <p class="fruta">Manzana</p>
  <p class="fruta">Pera</p>
  <p class="fruta">Plátano</p>
</div>
```

**Referencias:** [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/), [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function), [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)